# populating drop down values from the database

Tags: java, jsp, yui

This question might have been asked thousands of time, but I am unable to get this working.

I need to populate the drop down values from the database when the page gets loaded. I have a domain class of table is defined as ***"CountryList"***

I am getting the list of all the countries like

```
@RenderMapping(params = "action=studentPage")

    public String studentSetUpPage(RenderRequest request,
                RenderResponse response, ModelMap model) {


// some code

ArrayList<CountryList> getAllCountries = serviceClass.getAllCountries(id);

for(CountryList country : getAllCountries){

    System.out.println(" Country " + listCountry.getCountry());

}


}
```

**JSP Code**

```
<form action="<%=save%>" method="POST" name="createpage"                                            id="createPage">

<table>
    <c:forEach var="mainform1" items="${mainform2}">

<aui:select name="countrySelect" id="countrySelect"
          label="Country :" inlineLabel="Country:"
          showRequiredLabel="false">

          <c:forEach var="countryList"
            items="${mainform2.countryList}">
         <aui:option label="....."
         value="..........">
         </aui:option>
         </c:forEach>

</aui:select>

</c:forEach>
</table>
</form>
```

It's printing all the countries on the console.

I want to print these values in the drop down in the jsp. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Where have you set the data in the `mainform2` attribute and you are trying to access it by

```
items="${mainform2}"
```

Comment: You wrote `"${mainform2.countryList}"` have you set the property `countryList` in the mainform2 ?